# Cannot build Flutter App (Android) after install wechat_assets_picker

Tags: android, flutter

I recently installed `wechat_assets_picker`, however when trying to build for android I get the following error, nothing in thier docs about it and no issues on thier issue list either.

```
e: /Users/remelehane/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/photo_manager-0.6.0/android/src/main/kotlin/top/kikt/imagescanner/core/PhotoManagerDeleteManager.kt: (116, 36): Unresolved reference: R
e: /Users/remelehane/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/photo_manager-0.6.0/android/src/main/kotlin/top/kikt/imagescanner/core/PhotoManagerDeleteManager.kt: (119, 36): Unresolved reference: createTrashRequest
e: /Users/remelehane/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/photo_manager-0.6.0/android/src/main/kotlin/top/kikt/imagescanner/core/PhotoManagerPlugin.kt: (341, 84): Unresolved reference: R
e: /Users/remelehane/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/photo_manager-0.6.0/android/src/main/kotlin/top/kikt/imagescanner/core/utils/Android30DbUtils.kt: (34, 34): Unresolved reference: R
e: /Users/remelehane/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/photo_manager-0.6.0/android/src/main/kotlin/top/kikt/imagescanner/core/utils/IDBUtils.kt: (27, 67): Unresolved reference: R
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':photo_manager:compileReleaseKotlin'.        
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

The erroring line is `@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)` which from what I understand means this function on runs in version R of the android SDK, which is OS11, so should not be affecting the build?

I checked with the example project which is running SDK min 21 and compiled of 29.

Mine is running 19 and 21, however changign to 21 did not get around the build error so there must be more to is than that?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is as a result of the `compiledSdkVersion` being set to 29, it needs to be set to 30

Answer (score -1):

Each time you upgrade your pubspecs, or run a pub upgrade, you need to run `flutter clean`. And it should solved. Specific to the photo_manager.